# Is the choice of static and dynamic typing not visible to the programmers of the languages?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

From *Design Concepts in Programming Languages* by Turbak

> Although some **dynamically typed languages** have simple type markers (e.g., Perl variable names begin with a character that indicates the type of value: $ for
>   scalar values, @ for array values, and % for hash values (key/value pairs)), dynamically typed languages typically have
>   no explicit type annotations.
>
> The converse is true in **statically typed languages**,
>   where explicit type annotations are the norm. Most languages descended from
>   Algol 68 , such as Ada , C / C++ , Java , and Pascal , require that types be
>   explicitly declared for all variables, all data-structure components, and all function/procedure/method parameters and return values. However, some languages
>   (e.g., ML , Haskell , FX , Miranda ) achieve static typing without explicit type
>   declarations via a technique called type reconstruction or type inference.

**Question 1:** For dynamically typed languages which "have no explicit type annotations", do they need to infer/reconstruct the types/classes, by using some type/class reconstruction or type/class inference techniques,  as statically typed languages do?

**Question 2:**  The above quote says static or dynamic typing and   explicit or no type annotations can mix and match.

- Is the choice between  static and dynamic typing only internal to the implementations of programming languages, not visible to the programmers of the languages?
- Do programmers in programming languages only notice whether the languages use explicit type/class annotations or not, not whether the languages use static or dynamic typing?  Specifically, do  languages with explicit type/class annotations look the same to programmers, regardless of whether they are static or dynamic typing? Do  languages without explicit type/class annotations look the same to programmers, regardless of whether they are static or dynamic typing?

**Question 3:** If you can understand the following quote from     *Practical Foundation of Programming Languages* by Harper (a preview version is https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf),

- Do the syntax for numeral (abstract syntax num[n] or concrete syntax overline{n}) and abstraction (abstract syntax  fun(x.d) or concrete syntax λ(x)d ) use explicit types/classes with dynamic typing?
- If yes, is the purpose of using explicit types/classes to avoid type inference/reconstruction?

> **Section 22.1 Dynamically Typed PCF**
>
> To illustrate dynamic typing, we formulate a dynamically typed version
>   of PCF, called DPCF. The abstract syntax of DPCF is given by the
>   following grammar:
>
> ```
> Exp d :: = x x variable
>            num[n] overline{n}      numeral
>            zero zero      zero
>            succ(d) succ(d)      successor
>            ifz {d0; x.d1} (d) ifz d {zero → d0 | succ(x) → d1}      zero test
>            fun(x.d) λ(x)d      abstraction
>            ap(d1; d2) d1 (d2)      application
>            fix(x.d) fix x is d      recursion
> ```
>
> **There are two classes of values in DPCF**, the numbers, which have the form num[n], and
>   the functions, which have the form fun(x.d). The expressions zero and succ(d) are not
>   themselves values, but rather are constructors that evaluate to values. General recursion
>   is deﬁnable using a ﬁxed point combinator but is taken as primitive here to simplify the
>   analysis of the dynamics in Section 22.3.
>
> As usual, the abstract syntax of DPCF is what matters, but we use the concrete syntax
>   to improve readability. However, notational conveniences can obscure important details,
>   such as the tagging of values with their class and the checking of these tags at run-time.
>   For example, the concrete syntax for a number, overline{n}, suggests a “bare” representation, the
>   abstract syntax reveals that the number is labeled with the class num to distinguish it from
>   a function. Correspondingly, the concrete syntax for a function is λ (x) d, but its abstract
>   syntax, fun(x.d), shows that it also sports a class label. The class labels are required to
>   ensure safety by run-time checking, and must not be overlooked when comparing static
>   with dynamic languages.

Thanks.

Comment: The usual rule is one question per post.

Comment: Are you familiar with [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)?

Comment: Please remove all but one question from your post. You seem to be asking at least four very different ones. Keep in mind that argumentative, open-ended "discussion starters" are unsuited for this platform (as you should be well aware, you've been around for a while).

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1

No, dynamically-typed programming languages usually do not perform any kind of type inference. The common approach is to check types at runtime, and cause a runtime error or exception in case a type mismatch is found.

> Question 2

Having static or dynamic type checking is a choice which is visible to programmers. A program like

```
print "hello"
print (3 / "a string?")
```

in a statically-typed language will cause a compile-time type error (hence before it prints anything), while in a dynamic language the program will start, print `hello`, and then error out.

Also a program like

```
if 0==1:
    print (3 / "a string?")
```

will run perfectly fine in a dynamically-typed language, but won't compile if using static type checking.

> Question 3

There is no type inference, or type reconstruction being performed there. Types are not made explicit in the program. The runtime system can simply store a tag near values to remember their type (`number` or `function`), so that runtime type checking can be performed.